# Did Heine write “wo die Blumen sprießen” or “wo die Veilchen sprießen” in Frühlingsbotschaft?

Tags: poetry, german-language, heinrich-heine

> Kling' hinaus bis an das Haus,
>   wo die **Veilchen** sprießen:
>   Wenn du eine Rose schaust,
>   sag', ich lass sie grüßen.

Is the original text "**Veilchen** spriessen" or "**Blumen** spriessen"? I have seen both versions.

Comment: See [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/in-which-year-was-fr%c3%bchlingsbotschaft-by-heinrich-heine-published?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

I consulted Heinrich Heine: ***Sämtliche Werke*. Düsseldorfer Ausgabe**, in 16 volumes, published by Hoffmann und Campe in the 1990s. (This is the same edition I consulted for [this related question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5280/2191).)

The lines quoted in the question come from a poem starting with the line "Leise zieht durch mein Gemüt", i.e. poem VI of **Neuer Frühling**, which was included in the [**Neue Gedichte**](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Neue_Gedichte_(1844)), published by Hoffmann und Campe in 1844.

In the Düsseldorfer Ausgabe, the poem is on page 14 of volume 2 (*Neue Gedichte*). According to the notes and comments (page 350f), the source of the line "wo die Veilchen sprießen" is the second reprint of *Reisebilder von H. Heine. Zweiter Theil*, published in 1831 (the first edition was published in 1827). However, the variant with "Blumen" appears to be the authoritative one.